# Rails Routes - Id and name with spaces replaced with hyphens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing my first application in rails. I went through the [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters)
  documentation but unable to figure out how to setup the following route.

I have a ClientsController and the for the show action I want to display the client's first and last name with spaces replaced with hyphens, in the url.

Instead of the following

localhost:3000/clients/1

the link should be (first name : john, last name : doe)

localhost:3000/clients/1/john-doe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy here is to treat the name in the URL like a throw-away variable, since it's not being used as an identifier. Notice that in StackOverflow you can type any name you want, and as long as the id is correct you'll get the page you want. So we can do that too:

1. Define the normal routes using `resources :clients` so you can go to `/clients/1`
2. Define a another route `get 'clients/:id/:name', to: 'clients#show', as: :client_name`. This lets you go to `/clients/1/anything-you-want` and it will hit the `show` action in `ClientsController` with `id: 1` and `name: "anything-you-want"`.
3. Define a method to generate the url-name from the user's name. For simplicity I'll assume you have defined `User#url_name`, but it might make more sense to define `url_name(client)` in a helper since it's not really relevant to the model.
4. In your app, use `client_name_path(@client.id, @client.url_name)`; e.g., `client_name_path(1, "john-doe")`. This url-helper name is defined by our choice to use `as: :client_name` in the route. The return value of this call should be "/clients/1/john-doe", which we have already routed to the `ClientsController#show` action.

So far, links in your app will have the correct URL, but a user could still type in any name in the URL and it would persist in the address bar (even though the page would be fine). If you want to go further like StackOverflow and actually change the url to the correct name you might try in `ClientsController#show`, to `redirect_to client_name_path(@client.id, @client.url_name) if params[:name] != @client.url_name`. Just be careful with that to not get yourself into an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks.. this is nice and easy approach.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean `localhost:3000/clients/john-doe` not `localhost:3000/clients/1/john-doe`? (The `/1/` would be redundant in the latter case).

Your first option would be to define a `to_param` method in your `User` model. You would need to return a parameter starting with the id of your model:

```
def to_param
  [id, first_name, last_name].join("-")
end

User.find_by(last_name: "doe").to_param # => 1-john-doe
```

If you really don't want the ID in your user model, then consider using the Friendly ID gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

I'd urge caution against using `first-last` as an identifier in your route, however. First, what happens if you have two users with the same first/last name (it'll happen eventually)? Second, what if your users have unusual names, such as those with spaces or apostrophes (e.g. "O'neill", etc.)? You can always URL  encode such cases, but it won't look pretty.

Comment: +1 .. thanks for details answer. The first and last were meant to make the url seo friendly, like stackoverflow is doing, the id in the url is meant to be the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that out of the box in rails. But you can achieve that using [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem